# Finding out relation between multiple columns through data visualization in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, data-science, data-visualization

I have a pandas dataframe, Which has 3 columns : `clm A`, `clm B`, `clm C` and one target column `results.` I want to find out whether target is depending on all/any other column. If I can draw a graph, I might have some insights. I am new to data visualization, so I do not know how to do this.

I tried using 2 columns at a time, E.g.: I drew scatter plot for `Clm A, results`, and then for `Clm B, results` and so on but I think all 3 columns (A, B, C) collectively are determining values for results. Is there any way to visualize this?

Comment: What you want to do is a Principal Component Analysis (PCA) to determine which variable(s) is the most important on target result.

Comment: I already did that, Originally I had about 300 columns, which are reduced to 2 columns using PCA (namely clm A, clm B), but clm C is completely different from others, So I did not include it while calculating pca. Should I Include that also?

Comment: You can try it but only with your 3 columns.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.